# ignite server giving some thread related exception

Tags: ignite

One of ignite server giving some thread related exception.Below is the some stackTrace:

Can somebody tell why these thread related exceptions are coming.
I am getting this error when another server with same server instance name started.
I know that server is getting shut down due to the above reason.But why these thread related errors are coming. Ihave also posted the ignite server java code at the end.

```
Thread [name="ignite-update-notifier-timer", id=96, state=TIMED_WAITING, blockCnt=0, waitCnt=1]
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cluster.ClusterProcessor$UpdateNotifierTimerTask.safeRun(ClusterProcessor.java:707)
    at app//o.a.i.i.util.GridTimerTask.run(GridTimerTask.java:33)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)

Thread [name="exchange-worker-#43%CcPlatformUserRolesOrganizationAssociationServerGroupUsers%", id=97, state=RUNNABLE, blockCnt=97, waitCnt=1]
    at java.management@11.0.2/sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpThreads0(Native Method)
    at java.management@11.0.2/sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpAllThreads(ThreadImpl.java:502)
    at java.management@11.0.2/sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpAllThreads(ThreadImpl.java:490)
    at app//o.a.i.i.util.IgniteUtils.dumpThreads(IgniteUtils.java:1391)
    at app//o.a.i.i.processors.failure.FailureProcessor.process(FailureProcessor.java:143)
    - locked o.a.i.i.processors.failure.FailureProcessor@44d9dc1c
    at app//o.a.i.i.processors.failure.FailureProcessor.process(FailureProcessor.java:112)
    at app//o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2924)
    at app//o.a.i.i.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:119)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Thread [name="sys-#44%CcPlatformUserRolesOrganizationAssociationServerGroupUsers%", id=98, state=TIMED_WAITING, blockCnt=80, waitCnt=1]
Lock [object=java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@74fe8ae1, ownerName=null, ownerId=-1]
    at java.base@11.0.2/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:458)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1053)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Thread [name="sys-#45%CcPlatformUserRolesOrganizationAssociationServerGroupUsers%", id=99, state=TIMED_WAITING, blockCnt=52, waitCnt=1]
Lock [object=java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@74fe8ae1, ownerName=null, ownerId=-1]
    at java.base@11.0.2/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:458)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1053)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Thread [name="sys-#46%CcPlatformUserRolesOrganizationAssociationServerGroupUsers%", id=100, state=TIMED_WAITING, blockCnt=0, waitCnt=1]
Lock [object=java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@74fe8ae1, ownerName=null, ownerId=-1]
    at java.base@11.0.2/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:458)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1053)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base@11.0.2/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Here is the Ignite server Code.

```
public IgniteConfiguration createConfiguration() throws Exception {
    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

    cfg.setIgniteInstanceName("CcPlatformUserRolesOrganizationAssociationServerGroups");
    cfg.setSqlSchemas("public");
    TcpDiscoverySpi discovery = new TcpDiscoverySpi();

    TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();

    ipFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1:47500..47510"));

    discovery.setIpFinder(ipFinder);

    cfg.setDiscoverySpi(discovery);
    cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
    // setting Cache
    cfg.setCacheConfiguration(cacheGroupsCache());

    return cfg;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not exceptions or errors. It is a thread dump showing the activity and state of each thread inside the JVM at a particular moment in time. Ignite is configured to automatically log thread dumps whenever a failure is detected. You can use IGNITE_DUMP_THREADS_ON_FAILURE system property to change that.
More information here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/logging